# How do I solve this 3-D system of linear equations using Gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:

$x+2y+3z = -6$

$2x - 3y - 4z = 15$

$3x + 4y + 5z = -8$

I came up with this:

$x + 2y + 3z = -6$

$-7y - 10z = 18$

$5x + y + z = 7$

Can you tell me the best way forward? Also, am I doing it "wrong"?

Edit:

OK, here's what I got:

\begin{align}x + 2y + 3z &= -6\\
-14y - 20z &= 36\\
2y - 24z &= 55\end{align}

I'm starting to question whether this should have happened.

Comment: Always keep track of every step. Gaussian elimination requires very careful organization, because without stating explicitly what you are doing,  others can't retrace  what you got. (My question is then where did the third equation come from?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I proceeded the first time. Notice that at every step I am keeping track of exactly what I did (which is something you must do with Gaussian Elimination). Also, you should know that when I broke my own rule of meticulously tracking each and every step (i.e., I tried to rush through the computation), I made an error in arithmetic and had to go back and redo the bulk of these computations.

Start with the original system:
\begin{align}
x+2y+3z &= -6\\
2x - 3y - 4z &= 15\\
3x + 4y + 5z &= -8
\end{align}
Subtract twice the first equation from the second to get:
\begin{align}
x+2y+3z &= -6\\
 - 7y - 10z &= 27\\
3x + 4y + 5z &= -8
\end{align}
Subtract three times the first equation from the first to get:
\begin{align}
x+2y+3z &= -6\\
- 7y - 10z &= 27\\
-2y - 4z &= 10
\end{align}
Divide the third equation by $-2$ to get:
\begin{align}
x+2y+3z &= -6\\
- 7y - 10z &= 27\\
y + 2z &= -5
\end{align}
Subtract twice the third equation from the first to get:
\begin{align}
x-z &= 4\\
-7y-10z &= 27\\
y + 2z &= -5
\end{align}

And you should be able to take it from here. (Sorry this is less of a hint and more of a solution, but I wanted to exhibit exactly where this elimination method was going from the first step).

---

One of the keys to this was taking the first equation, noticing I had a $1$ coefficient on $x$, and setting about to eliminate $x$ from every other equation. I then looked at $y$, and noticed that with a couple of row operations, I could get one of the other equations to have a $1$ coefficient on $y$, allowing me to eliminate it.

Notice that when I stopped (and where you take over), I had eliminated the the $x's$ from the second and third equations, $y$'s from the first equation, and now I am set up in a way that lets me eliminate $y$'s from the second equation, yielding the solution for $z$. Once I have done this, I use the equation giving the solution for $z$ eliminate $z$ from the first and third equations, yielding the solution to the system.

Comment: How did you know to subtract twice the first equation from the second one?

Comment: What are the coefficients on $x$ in those two equations? In the first equation, it's a $1$, and in the second equation, it's a $2$. To eliminate the $x$ term from the second equation, I need to subtract something that eliminates $2x$ out of the second equation. If you multiply the first equation by $2$, it gives you a $2x$ along with other things. Subtracting this "new" first equation from the second equation will get rid of the $x$ term in the second equation.